# Flurry only logging time events, not regular ones

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, analytics, flurry

I am trying to use Flurry to collect analytics within my iOS 5.x and 6.x App. 
Overall what I do seems to work, however in the events tab of the flurry dashboard I can only see one type of events, those that are timed. I should say that I've been doing tests for more than a week, for even though it is not real time, I've given it more than 72 hours to update.
Up to my knowledge the installation is fine. I have added and copied the .h and .a file to my project, they are referenced and the library is being linked in the Link binaries to libraries section in the Target Settings.

Here is some code:
In the application delegate I have the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary  *)launchOptions
{
    [Flurry startSession:@"MYKEY"]; 
    [Flurry logAllPageViews:self.navigationController]; // Pageviews logging appear to be working
```

Now, at some part of my code which is definitely executed I do:

```
[Flurry logEvent:@"SOME_EVENT_NAME"];
// The event above never shows
```

At some point of my application I do:

```
[Flurry logEvent:@"SOME_TIMED_EVENT_NAME" timed:YES];
```

And then after some time I do:

```
[Flurry endTimedEvent:@"SOME_TIMED_EVENT_NAME" withParameters:nil];
```

As I was saying, the interesting thing is that the Timed Events and the Page Views do seem to work as they show up in the Flurry dashboard, but the conventional events do not.
I am about to try a Tier 2 event see how that goes.
In any case the problem seems really strange to me, needless to say how frustrating is becoming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that Flurry does not report the data produced with the iOS simulator, and I believe that this was what was happening.
Unfortunately I never found this in the documentation, and therefore do not have strong proof of such claim. However, the data produced by using the application on actual devices seems to have been reported appropriately to the flurry system.